# bash + reduce comparing line to short way

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I want to reduce the following comparing line to short way

```
   [[ $ANSWER = YES ]] || [[ $ANSWER = yes ]] || [[ $ANSWER = Yes ]] && echo your answer is really yes
```

so I tries the following without success

```
[[ $ANSWER = ([YES|Yes|yes]) ]] && echo your answer is really yes
[[ $ANSWER = [YES|Yes|yes]   ]] && echo your answer is really yes
```

Please advice what is it the right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` allows you to do regex matching. To match all possible case combinations of yes, the following would work:

```
if [[ "$ANSWER" =~ ^[Yy][Ee][Ss]$ ]]; then echo "yes!"; fi
```

Note that this will also match `yEs` or `yES`, which your original code doesn't. If you don't want to watch these, go with [alfasin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752301/112968)

Comment: VERY NICE ( THIS ANSWER IS OUT OF THE BOX ) +1

Comment: What the hell? This does not even work because of the quotes. Also it would print ``yes!`` for ``WHATTHEYESISTHAT?``

Comment: This is valid but only up to Bash 3.1. 3.2 changed that behaviour. Naturally anything inside quotes should be parsed literally which I believe is the proper way.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko: thanks for noticing. Fixed the regular expression

Answer (score 2):

shopt allows you to change shell behavior

```
shopt -s nocasematch
[[ $ANSWWER = "yes" ]]
```

[shopt - bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

Comment: and how to disable it ?

Comment: You can check it in the link in the answer `shopt -u nocasematch`

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex:

```
if [[ $ANSWER =~ ^(YES|Yes|yes)$ ]] ; then echo 'your answer is really yes'; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way , maybe the shortest:

```
[[ $ANSWER =~ ^[Yy][Ee][Ss]$ ]] && echo your answer is really yes
```

Or using typeset (to avoid a **glogal shopt**) :

```
typeset -l ANSWER
ANSWER=YES
[[ $ANSWER = yes ]] && echo your answer is really yes
```

To disable typeset just:

```
typeset +l ANSWER
```

From bash man:

> Using **+** instead of **-** turns off the attribute

Comment: about typeset -l , how to perform falback of this?

Comment: Your regex is wrong. Try to match ``WHATTHEYESISTHAT?``

Comment: Corrected, thaks @Aleks-DanielJakimenko

Answer (score 1):

Wow, people are suggesting to use grep, shopt nocasematch, regexps... While the simplest solution is this:

```
[[ ${ANSWER^^} = 'YES' ]] && echo 'your answer is really yes'
```

That's it. You can read about parameter expansion [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification).

P.S. I wonder why nobody [suggested to use extended globs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24755362/2698019) :D

Comment: WOW its exelent solution

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it using `grep`:

```
ANSWER="yEs";
if grep -qi "^yes$" <<< "$ANSWER"; then
    echo 'your answer is really yes'
fi
```

Explanation:

1. Grep returns 0 if matches, so you can use it for `if`
2. `-q` is for quiet so there will be no output
3. `-i` is fo case insensitive.
4. Mind you the anchors `^` and `$` which will match the string exactly

Answer (score 0):

Just [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob):

```
[[ $ANSWER = [Yy][Ee][Ss] ]] && echo 'your answer is really yes'
```

Extended glob:

```
shopt -s extglob
[[ $ANSWER = @(YES|Yes|yes) ]] && echo 'your answer is really yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another proper form is

```
[[ $ANSWER =~ ^[Yy][Ee][Ss]$ ]]
```

It's valid starting Bash 3.0 up.

Note: [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752342/445221) already fixed his answer so don't mind this.

Comment: Is it a massive flashmob of giving a wrong answer? I don't get it. Try ``WHATTHEYESISTHAT?``.

Comment: What's a "massive flashmob"?

Comment: I don't know, people just kept writing the same wrong answer again and again.